# Scala: check that a case class tree doesn't contain any null

Tags: scala

I use a Scala json serializer and just discovered that it doesn't set default values to case classes en deserialization, but instead set these missing values to null.

Fortunatly it didn't damage much my system until now mostly because of CRUD only fields being set to null, but in the future, I absolutely want to enforce that my JSON payloads do not have any null values.

My Json payloads are generally some kind of tree of case classes with lists and primitives.
It is generally pretty simple, like a `case class Person(addresses: List[Address], name: String, ...)` with `case class Address(street: String, number: Int)` ...

---

- Is there a way to ensure that a case class has no null field in it?
- In case a null is found, is there a way to set it automatically to the default value instead of null?
- Would it work for nested case classes?

I guess there's something to do with the `Product` trait but don't really know where to start.

Comment: What are you using for serialization?  Spray?

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to put the lib. I'm using https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala and will perhaps change to a more appropriate serializer when I have time

Answer (score 1):

You can add a requirement on the case class so serialization will fail:

```
case class Person(  name: String, 
                    ssn: String,
                    homePhone: Option[Long],
                    cellPhone: Option[Long]){

  require(homePhone.isDefined || cellPhone.isDefined, "Person requires at least one phone number")
  require(ssn.length() == 9 && ssn.forall(Character.isDigit(_)), "ssn must be a String of 9 digits")
}
```

Comment: That seems really sad. The whole point is that his type doesn't allow it to be `None`/`null`. This would force the rest of the program to deal with a possibly absent phone number.

Comment: My example was based on a use case I had where it was only a problem if they were all None.  It sounds like your deserializer library is not the best if it is putting nulls in there.  I'm only familiar with Spray-Json which doesn't have that problem.  You either get a deserialization error if a field is not an option and not present or you get a None if the missing field is an option.  Spray-Json is stand alone and can be used independently of the rest of Spray.

Answer (score -1):

Can be this a solution?

```
def isCaseClassEmpty(product: Product): Boolean =
    product.productIterator.forall {
      case None => true
      case Some(x: Product) => isCaseClassEmpty(x)
      case _ => false
    }

case class Inner(b: Option[Int])
case class Root(a: Option[String]: inner: Option[Inner])

val root = Root(None, None))
isCaseClassEmpty(root) // true

val root = Root(None, Some(Inner(None)))
isCaseClassEmpty(root) // true

val root = Root(None, Some(Inner(Some(5))))
isCaseClassEmpty(root) // false

val root = Root(Some("test"), None)
isCaseClassEmpty(root) // false
```

Cheers :-)

Comment: None and null are not equivalent in scala. You can still have NPEs in scala. So in your words ```Root(None,None) == Root(null,null) //returns false```. With your solution you also assume that all members of the case class are of type ```Option[_]```